# why assert_equal() in Ruby on Rails sometimes seem to compare by Identity and sometimes by value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, integration-testing, assert, equality

it was very weird that yesterday, I was do an integration test in Rails and

```
assert_equal array_of_obj1, array_of_obj2     # obj1 from db, obj2 created in test
```

and it failed.  The values shown inside the array and objects were identical.  If I change the test to

```
assert array_of_obj1 == array_of_obj2
```

Then it will pass.

But today, the first  test actually passed.  What reason could it be?  Is assert_equal always using `==` or `.equal?` in Rails 2.2 or 2.3.5?

Answer (score 2):

`assert_equal` does always use the == method. This behavior is from the Ruby core and is not overridden or changed in Rails.  You can read the documentation for `assert_equal` [here](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/test/unit/rdoc/Test/Unit/Assertions.html#method-i-assert_equal).

However, it should be noted that the == method behaves differently depending on which object it is called on.

For example, an Object == method compares actual [object identity](https://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.html#method-i-3D-3D). However, a String == method compares the [values of the string](https://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#method-i-3D-3D).